# switching from luigi to airflow

Tags: airflow, luigi

I have a relatively simple task that starts with running on 1.2 mio files and having a pipeline for each one of them (with multiple steps where the intermediate products are saved). I have implemented this in luigi: https://gist.github.com/wkerzendorf/395c85a2955002412be302d708329f7f. I like that Luigi uses the filesystem to see if a task has been done or not. 
I have also found an implementation where I can delete an intermediate product and the pipeline will recreate all the dependent products (so I can change the pipeline). 
How would I do this in airflow (or maybe I should stick with Luigi?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know how Luigi works. I use mainly Apache Airflow. Airflow is a workflow management system. It means it does not transfer data, transform it or generate some(Although it generates logs and there is a concept called `Xcom` which allows to exchange messages between tasks, allowing more nuanced forms of control and shared state.), eg. Apache Nifi. But it defines the dependencies of each Task you instantiate it using `Operators`, eg. `BashOperator`. For it to know if a task is done, it checks the signal returned by the same task.

Following an example of what you want do implemented in Airflow.

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import glob
import gzip
import shutil

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_dag', default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60))


def extract_gzs():
    for filename in glob.glob('/1002/*.gz')
        with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f_in, open(filename[:-3], 'wb') as f_out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)


extractGZ = PythonOperator(
    task_id='extract_gz',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=extract_gzs(),
dag=dag)


cmd_cmd="""
your sed script!
"""

sed_script = BashOperator(
    task_id='sed_script', 
    bash_command=cmd_cmd, 
    dag=dag)


extractGZ.set_downstream(sed_script)
```

1. Import the operators that you want to use in Airflow (and of course if you need other classes/libraries)
2. Define your Dag. Here in the variable `args` i defined the `owner` and the `start_date` parameter.
3. Then instantiate your DAG. Here i have named it example_dag, attributed its definition variable, schedule_interval and after which time should it timeout(there is many more parameter to use according to your needs)
4. created a python function extract_gzs()
5. instanciated a `PythonOperator` where i call my python func
6. Doing the same with the bash code
7. Determining the dependencies between the two task intances

Of course there is many more ways to implement the same idea. To adapt according to needs!
PS: [Here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/example_dags) there is some examples with Apache Airflow

Comment: Maybe, I'm misunderstanding this whole pipeline thing. I assumed that you build a pipeline then you feed it one dataset that is then transformed along the lines of this pipeline. That would mean one pipeline which works on 1.2 mio files. Is that not the right way to think about this. It should be trivial to do make an airflow pipeline that runs sed on a file and then apply this to the 1.2 mio files, no?

Comment: @WolfgangKerzendorf Check my modified answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try. It's still not entirely how I imagine this to be. I would like to build a pipeline for a file and then somehow make something push each file through this thing.